# converting string array into int array

Tags: java, arrays, int

this is what i have so far, i need to convert this string array into just an array of integers, the string array looks something like this

```
wholef[0] = "2 3 4";
wholef[1] = "1 3 4";
wholef[2] = "5 3 5";
wholef[3] = "4 5 6";
wholef[4] = "3 10 2";
```

these values come from a text file that i read from but now i need to convert this into one big array of integers, im trying to use the split method but im not sure if it will work on this kind of setup. if anyone can give me a better way it would be nice but i just need to convert this into an array of integers, thats really all i need.

```
for(int k = 0; k < fline; k++)
    {
        String[] items = wholef[k].replaceAll(" ", "").split(",");

        int[] parsed = new int[wholef[k].length];

        for (int i = 0; i < wholef[k].length; i++)
        {
            try 
            {
                parsed[i] = Integer.parseInt(wholef[i]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
        }
    }
```

This is the new code im using now, its very close cause i only get one error

```
int q = 0;
        for (String crtLine : wholef) 
        {
            int[] parsed = new int[wholef.length];

            String[] items = crtLine.split(" ");
            for (String crtItem: items) 
            {
                parsed[q++] = Integer.parse(crtItem);
            }
        }
```

the error is this
java:97: error: cannot find symbol parsed[q++} = Integer.parse(crtItem);
                                                        ^
symbol: method parse(String)
location: class Integer
1 error

Comment: What are you doing with the brackets? I don't see any in your `String`s?

Comment: honestly i have no idea why that was in there but it has been fixed

Comment: `parsed[q++] = Integer.parse(crtItem)` should be `parsed[q++] = Integer.parseInt(crtItem)`

Comment: Perhaps this was mocked up code for the question, but it's risky to do `catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};` without reacting in some way (throwing it again?), or at least including a comment affirming that you intend to quietly drop non-integer strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This take your string array and dumps it into intwholef[n..total];
If you want it into a 2D array or an object array you have to do some additional. Then you can do an array of objects, and have each set of values as an attribute.

```
 String[] parts = wholef[0].split(" ");
 int[] intwholef= new int[parts.length];

 for(int n = 0; n < parts.length; n++) {
    intwholef[n] = Integer.parseInt(parts[n]);
  }
```

Comment: got this to work nicely, my only question is, when i have the variables in the new array im unable to use them outside of the for loop, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
for (String crtLine : wholef) {
     String[] items = crtLine.split(" ");
     for (String crtItem: items) {
          parsed[i++] = Integer.parseInt(crtItem);
     }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you reset i every iteration of wholef and that parsed gets set to correct size.

Comment: That would break it - writing the same 3 elements into the array. As size unknown I would suggest using a List then calling toArray().

Comment: If it is known that each `.split()` will result in exactly 3 strings, `parsed` array can be safely initialized like this: `int[] parsed = new int[3*wholef.length]`, if not, @bmorris591 is right, it will be better to have a `List`

Comment: This is good, i narrowed it down to 1 error but im not sure on how to fix it. i will add to details underneath all of my post

Comment: `Integer.parse` isn't a method.